# How to bind to a port less than 1024 in Android?

Tags: android, port, privilege, rooted-device

I have an Android service trying to bind to a server socket port 24. As it is privileged port, it is failing with a bind exception.
I am wondering what I need to do to get this working.
I see this was asked couple of times in this forum, but without a resolution.

This service runs on a device that runs on Android. We build android platform for the device. We have all the control we need.

Comment: Based on general Linux knowledge, only processes that run as root can listen on port 24. Can you even run Java apps as root?

Comment: Agreed. The process must run as root, or perhaps as a user ID with admin privileges (not sure if Android supports that Linux concept). Usually, if you control the device, you're not writing daemons in Java, but in C/C++, and starting them using normal Linux daemon support.

Comment: The "su ..." way of elevating privileges is not an option as I am binding to a port. I am not trying to spawn a shell script. As every android app is basically a process forked from zygote, unless zygote elevates privilege based on SOMETHING, you can't bind. I am wondering if zygote allows that or not. If it does, what is that SOMETHING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind to a port less than 1024, you need to be root and there are two ways of doing that.

1. **System app** : The app should be installed into /system/apps folder from where it shall be run as root. However, there are some signature issues for which help is [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature). Distribution is also a problem with system apps.
2. **su binary** : The su binary can be invoked using a simple `exec("su -c [command]")`. But things are easier said than done. You need to run an android processes not just a single command. Hence, there is [libsuperuser](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) which provides you the methods and has a full-length [doc page](http://su.chainfire.eu/).

Comment: For the record, with 1 even if you become a system app, you still don't run as `root`, only `system`, and still can't bind low ports.

Comment: So, does the proposed solution #1 (system app privileges) work or not? @DuBistKomisch's comment suggests that it doesn't but this is the accepted answer. Has anybody tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar question: [Run secure API calls as root, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010796/run-secure-api-calls-as-root-android), though they are trying to run as root for a different reason.

That made me wonder about installing 'system apps', and I saw this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27/rooted-how-to-install-a-system-app