# SMB server on Android (non default port)

Tags: java, android, alfresco, smb

I'm working on a project to develop an SMB server on Android, and for that i'm using the free Alfresco JLAN server implementation.
The question is that i can't use the default ports (445, 139, 138).
How can i access the server which is working in my android on ports 1445, 1139, 1138 ?
I tried port forwarding, any idea?

Comment: Note that i can't forward ports on android because i can't use any privileged ports (<1024)

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870898/how-to-bind-to-a-port-less-than-1024-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make use of any server in the middle to pipe the content stream from port 445 to 1445, I guess you can't make it without rooting your Android phone.