# Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android

Tags: android

I am trying to add conference call from my application,through reflection am trying if canDial is true or false,but returning security exception.Attached is the log file.

```
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission    Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.provider.Telephony.SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED from pid=1062, uid=10056
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:1548)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendStickyBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:726)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendStickyBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:297)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmServiceStateTracker.updateSpnDisplay(GsmServiceStateTracker.java:609)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmServiceStateTracker.pollStateDone(GsmServiceStateTracker.java:948)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmServiceStateTracker.pollState(GsmServiceStateTracker.java:782)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmServiceStateTracker.handleMessage(GsmServiceStateTracker.java:378)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-07 04:24:36.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know your suggestions to get this fixed.

Comment: will you show me manifest  permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would probably need to sign your application with the same key as the same system app and request for sharing the same user id with them.

You can look into the following links for further info:

- [How to programatically hide Caller ID on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510856/how-to-programatically-hide-caller-id-on-android)
- [Run secure API calls as root, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010796/run-secure-api-calls-as-root-android)

PS: Posted as answer because it was a bit too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks Ali for the response.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial` - looks like what you are trying to do requires a permission. The permission should be specified in AndroidManifest file.