# Not able to make a call when #31# is added

Tags: android, phone-call

I am trying to implement calling facility from my app. When some condition is true, I am hiding my caller id  by adding #31# before my number. Although if #31# is not added, call is made perfectly allright but when #31# is added, blank screen pops up, as if the Phone app is loading, and my application screen comes back. My code snippet is  this

```
        String ph = "123456789";            
        String phNumber;
        if (hideCallerId) {
            phNumber = "#31#" + ph;
        }
        else {
            phNumber = ph; 
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
```

**Case 1:** when phNumber is 123456789, then call is made without problem.

**Case 2:** when phNumber is #31#123456789, then blank screen pops up and user comes back to my application screen.

Although when I am dialing from my device using #31#123456789, call is successfully made. 
What I am missing out. Can anybody help me out.

Links didn't helped me [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510856/how-to-programatically-hide-caller-id-on-android).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to encode the phone number.

```
String phonenumber = "03012345,1234,#31#,98765"; // , = pauses
encodedPhonenumber = URLEncoder.encode(phonenumber, "UTF-8");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedPhonenumber)));
```

You may want to have a look at this one. [Not able to make a call when #31# is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065842/not-able-to-make-a-call-when-31-is-added)

Comment: Ya its working. But can you explain me why do we need to encode it. I am not getting why do we need to do this, but in  dial simple inputting it is enabling us to dial

Comment: Can't point out the exact reason but I guess android finds some difficulty in reading '#'. thus need to be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer but my rep isn't high enough for a comment. Is there any chance you have phnumber declared as an int or anything? Maybe the #'s are messing it up?

If that doesn't work have you tried using `ACTION_DIAL`? the android developer site has more info on the differences between them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL). Hope it helps.

Comment: For that matter, if you don't need the original number ("123456789") by itself you can use just the one variable. Bit simpler but it won't help with your problem!

Comment: Hey boundless. Thanks for replying. Ya i will check this out. Glad u mentioned what may be wrong. And Nope my phnumber is a string variable. and also dial is taking me to dial screen, its not dialing the number which i am passing. And I need to dial the number from my app screen.

Comment: Although your answer is not what I needed but still points to some serious stuff thus +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the `'#'` because it ***behaves like a dial command***, then if you set your action call intent data with a number starting with `'#'`, it will instead call a blank number, trying to dial a number like ***8488449#848*** if not encoded will dial ***`8488449`*** that's why you need to encode at least the `'#'` symbol with `Uri.encode("#")` 
for example to dial 8488449#848, i will do the following: 
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:8488449"+Uri.encode("#")+"848"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but the project is long gone. but still thanks for input

Comment: You're welcome! ... just hope it will clarify things for some body else facing that issue.