# How to hide caller ID info like phone number on receiver side phone replaceing with some text in android?

Tags: android

> In my application,I want to make appear some text like "Private Number" on receiver side cell on caller Id instead of phone number,so that receiver should not know the phone number where he/she is getting call from.
>   I researched a lot, but I couldn't find exact way to do this.
>   Can anyone help me,I will be thankful.

Comment: it depends on your network provider,you can't change it..there is a way that you install your app in the other phone and then you can manage it,i think that is the only way to do it.hope it will help.

Comment: This question has your answer.
Enjoy !!

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510856/how-to-programatically-hide-caller-id-on-android/9839006#9839006

Comment: But it is not possible to install such a app for every receiver device to make it possible...

Comment: Thanks sid,but still there is no proper solution to achieve my target,I already have tried with reflections but it was giving me security error,for that they have given solution to launch app as a system app,but i dont know how to do that and after knowing that also would it be possible or not??? I m not sure and I already have spent much time on this,but my deadline is near to come...so I m requesting to give me exact solution where I can get exact way to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

If You Have Android Phone Then You Must Try This Out:

1. Go to Settings.
2. Call settings
3. Additional settings
4. Wait until it initializes the options
5. Caller ID
6. Hide number
7. Go back and you're done